# Numbers uninstall reinstall

Tags: macos, numbers

Lately Numbers has been quitting unexpectedly on my MacBook Air and all the pre-installed templates are gone. Also it quits when working on formulas.

I'm thinking I could store documents in the cloud and uninstall and reinstall.

Is this possible? Will Apple charge me for a new Numbers App?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers is free from the [app store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825), so reinstalling should not be a problem.